# How to extract all the url's from a website?

Tags: python, unix

I am writing a programme in Python to extract all the urls from a given website. All the url's from a site not from a page.
As I suppose I am not the first one who wants to do that I was wondering if there was a ready made solution or if I have to write the code myself.

Answer (score 0):

It's not gonna be easy, but a decent starting point would be to look into these two libraries:

[urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html)
[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: PyQuery is also a life saver http://packages.python.org/pyquery/api.html ... You'll be able to query the DOM like in jQuery

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any ready made scripts that does this on a quick google search.

Using the `scrapy` framework makes this almost trivial.

The time consuming part would be learning how to use scrapy. THeir tutorials are great though and shoulndn't take you that long.

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

Creating a solution that others can use is one of the joys of being part of a programming community.  iF a scraper doesn't exist you can create one that everyone can use to get all links from a site!

Answer (score 0):

The given answers are what I would have suggested (+1).

But if you really want to do something quick and simple, and you're on a *NIX platform, try this:

```
lynx -dump YOUR_URL | grep http
```

Where YOUR_URL is the URL that you want to check. This **should** get you all the links you want (except for links that are not fully written)

Answer (score 0):

You first have to download the page's HTML content using a package like [urlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) or [requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests).

After that, you can use [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to extract the URLs. In fact, [their tutorial](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) shows how to extract all links enclosed in `<a>` elements as a specific example:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
# http://example.com/elsie
# http://example.com/lacie
# http://example.com/tillie
```

If you also want to find links not enclosed in `<a>` elements, you'll may have to write something more complex on your own.

EDIT: I also just came across two Scrapy link extractor classes that were created specifically for this task:

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html